# Converting Whole Number to Date

Tags: excel, date, type-conversion, data-conversion, helper

I have a column of numbers that has the visual appearance of YYYYMM. Ex. 201611. Excel I think is recognizing it as a whole number. I'm trying to convert this into a date format. I'd like excel to recognize this as 11-2016 I've tried creating a column that puts a dash between the numbers and trying to convert that column to date but that hasn't seemed to work either. Ex. 2016-11. Any helper column suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I just can't seem to find a workaround to recognize this number. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=Date(Left(A1,4),Right(A1,2),1)` should do it, then format as "MM-YYYY".

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I needed...Thank you!